# How do I find $L_{22}$ from LQ-decomposition when using Hankel matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, control-theory, projection-matrices, system-identification

Assume that we have input vector $y_k \in \Re^{pxN}, u_k \in \Re^{mxN}$.

The vectors can be interpreted as:

$$u_k = (u_0 , u_1, u_2, u_3, \dots , u_{N-1})$$
$$y_k = (y_0 , y_1, y_2, y_3, \dots , y_{N-1})$$

Yes, $u_k, y_k$ can contains multiple dimensions.

So. I create my hankel matrices.

$$U = \begin{bmatrix}
u_0 & u_1 & \dots & u_{j-1}\\ 
u_1 & u_2 & \dots & u_{j}\\ 
\vdots &  \vdots& \ddots & \vdots\\ 
u_{i-1} & u_i & \dots & u_{i+j-2}
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$Y = \begin{bmatrix}
y_0 & y_1 & \dots & y_{j-1}\\ 
y_1 & y_2 & \dots & y_{j}\\ 
\vdots &  \vdots& \ddots & \vdots\\ 
y_{i-1} & y_i & \dots & y_{i+j-2}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then I use LQ-decomposition to find $L_{22}$.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
U\\ 
Y
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
L_{11} & 0\\ 
L_{21} & L_{22} 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
Q_1\\ 
Q_2
\end{bmatrix}$$

The problem here is that I don't know the dimension of $L_{11}, L_{21}, L_{22}$. I know that the $L$-matrix and $Q$-matrix dimension. But no more!

If we try to simulate this method, we will first made up two vectors $u_k$ and $y_k$.

Then we use this code to create our hankel matricies. We determine the row dimension $i$ and column dimension $j$

```
U = hank(u, i, j)
Y = hank(y, i, j)
```

-

```
function [H] = hank(g, i, j)
  % Create hankel matrix
  H = cell(i, j); 

  for i = 1:i
    for j = 1:j
      H{i,j} = g(:,1+i+j-2);
    end
  end

  % Cell to matrix
  H = cell2mat(H);
end
```

Then we use this code to find the $L$-matrix.

```
L = triu(qr([U;Y]'))'
```

I have made a test. Consider this as a impulse response.

```
>> u = 0.1:0.1:4;
>> y = sin(u)./u;
>> U = hank(u, 9, 10); %i = 9, j = 10
>> Y = hank(y, 9, 10)
>> L = triu(qr([U;Y]'))'
L =

  -1.96214   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.24245  -0.14639   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.52275  -0.29277   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.80306  -0.43916   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -3.08337  -0.58554   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -3.36367  -0.73193   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000  -0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -3.64398  -0.87831   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000  -0.00000  -0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -3.92428  -1.02470   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000  -0.00000  -0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -4.20459  -1.17108   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000  -0.00000  -0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.55531  -1.51407  -0.01761  -0.01546   0.01204   0.01140  -0.01846   0.00061  -0.00066  -0.00530
  -2.49022  -1.51018  -0.01708  -0.01481   0.01152   0.01107  -0.01769   0.00059  -0.00063  -0.00507
  -2.41765  -1.50114  -0.01644  -0.01409   0.01093   0.01067  -0.01682   0.00056  -0.00060  -0.00482
  -2.33803  -1.48701  -0.01571  -0.01328   0.01028   0.01020  -0.01585   0.00052  -0.00057  -0.00454
  -2.25182  -1.46787  -0.01488  -0.01239   0.00958   0.00968  -0.01479   0.00049  -0.00053  -0.00423
  -2.15954  -1.44384  -0.01398  -0.01144   0.00882   0.00910  -0.01365   0.00045  -0.00049  -0.00390
  -2.06171  -1.41507  -0.01299  -0.01042   0.00801   0.00847  -0.01244   0.00041  -0.00044  -0.00355
  -1.95890  -1.38174  -0.01193  -0.00935   0.00716   0.00780  -0.01116   0.00036  -0.00040  -0.00318
  -1.85171  -1.34403  -0.01081  -0.00824   0.00628   0.00708  -0.00983   0.00032  -0.00035  -0.00279
```

Here we can see clearly that $L$-matrix has a lower triangular shape. But I still don't know how I should split $L$ into $L_{11}, L_{21}, L_{22}$.

The dimension of $L$ is $2ixj$.

**Question:**

Do you know how to split $L$ into $L_{11}, L_{21}, L_{22}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a good thumb rule that assume that $j$ should always be exactly twice bigger that $i$.

Example: Just assume that i = 5 and j = 10.

Then change the function to this:

```
function [L11, L21, L22] = lq(U, Y, i, j)
  [Q, L] = qr([U;Y]');

  % Rechange them all!
  Q = Q';
  L = L';

  L11 = L(1:i,1:i);
  L21 = L((1+i):end, 1:i);
  L22 = L((1+i):end, (1+i):j);
end
```

Then we run the code

```
L =

  -1.96214   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.24245  -0.14639   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.52275  -0.29277   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.80306  -0.43916   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -3.08337  -0.58554   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.55531  -1.51407  -0.01761  -0.01546   0.01204  -0.02235   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.49022  -1.51018  -0.01708  -0.01481   0.01152  -0.02149   0.00012   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.41765  -1.50114  -0.01644  -0.01409   0.01093  -0.02050   0.00024   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.33803  -1.48701  -0.01571  -0.01328   0.01028  -0.01940   0.00035   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.25182  -1.46787  -0.01488  -0.01239   0.00958  -0.01819   0.00047   0.00000   0.00000  -0.00000

L11 =

  -1.96214   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.24245  -0.14639   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.52275  -0.29277   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -2.80306  -0.43916   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000
  -3.08337  -0.58554   0.00000   0.00000   0.00000

L21 =

  -2.5553104  -1.5140683  -0.0176128  -0.0154571   0.0120366
  -2.4902197  -1.5101795  -0.0170764  -0.0148142   0.0115172
  -2.4176501  -1.5011413  -0.0164395  -0.0140855   0.0109313
  -2.3380291  -1.4870099  -0.0157068  -0.0132761   0.0102828
  -2.2518239  -1.4678721  -0.0148834  -0.0123919   0.0095764

L22 =

  -0.022351   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
  -0.021490   0.000120   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
  -0.020504   0.000238   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
  -0.019400   0.000354   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
  -0.018185   0.000467   0.000000   0.000000  -0.000000
```